# In flask, Is it possible to use url convertor without splitting them using slash '/'?

Tags: python, flask

I have a route:

```
 @app.route("/login/<user>/<timestamp>")
 def user(user, timestamp):.
```

But, I need it in this form -

```
 @app.route("/login/<user><timestamp>")
 def user(user, timestamp):.
```

i.e without the slash('/').

Is there any way to do it ?

Comment: Problem is: how is flask supposed to split the two? What is the *separator* in between.

Comment: Any particular reason why you need it in that format?

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer**: It is possible given the two parameters have a non-overlapping pattern. By giving it a wildcard-pattern however (you did not specify the converter). It will result in the fact that all content is handled to the `user`. That being said, it is advisable to have a clear *separator*.

As is specified in the [documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/#variable-rules), you can define variables by writing them like HTML tags, like `<var>`, you can also specify a converter, like `<converter:var>`. If you do *not* specify a converter, the parameter is assumed to be a string that can *not* contain slashes.

There are however other converters, like `int`, `float`, `path` and `uuid`.

If the patterns are written in such way that it is clear when the first pattern ends, and the second pattern begins, then it this can be handled. For example:

```
@app.route("/login/<int:day><user>")
```

can work, given `user` can not start with a digit, since here once the sequence of digits ends, Flask will parse the `<user>` parameter.

By writing `@app.route("/login/<user><timestamp>")` however, the two patterns are overlapping: if we do not have a parsing *strategy* any split could be a valid one. Since the engine is *greedy* if I recall correctly, in practice it will result in the fact that `user` takes all characters, and `timestamp` none.

Since the default `string` does *not* include a slash, we know that the slash acts as a clear separator, since it is not included in both variables in your example.